# KineticJS: How can I include custom canvas shapes in a toDataURL function

Tags: javascript, todataurl

My problem started with the version 5 of KineticJS, before that it was not a problem. Native KineticJS shapes such as squares and circles can be saved to an image file using the stage.toDataURL function. But it doesn't work for non-Kinetic shapes drawn with normal canvas methods such as beginPath(); and canvas.fill(); (version 4 did this fine). The following code draws two rectangles, one red and one blue. The red is custom, the blue is a native kinetic rectangle.

```
<body>
   <div id="container"></div>
      <button id="save">
        Save as image
      </button>     
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"> </script>
<script>
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 400,
    y: 80,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
  });


  layer.add(box);
  stage.add(layer);

  var canvas = layer.getCanvas().getContext('2d');
  canvas.beginPath();   
  canvas.setAttr('strokeStyle', 'black');
  canvas.setAttr('fillStyle', '#FF2222');
  canvas.setAttr('lineWidth', 8);
  canvas.rect(50,80,100,50);
  canvas.stroke();
  canvas.fill();


  document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
    stage.toDataURL({
      callback: function(dataUrl) {
        window.location.href = dataUrl; 
      }
    });
  }, false);
</script>
</body>
```

Both shapes appear, but only the blue rectangle appears in the image generated by the toDataURL function. The way they are drawn has changed in KineticJS 5, where you set attributes for fillStyle etc. so I'm thinking that may have something to do with it, or maybe the fact that the custom shape is added after the layer is added to the stage...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, between recent versions much has changed, and this has probably broken something in your drawing function.

You should consult the [official docs](http://kineticjs.com/docs/) on each item, but basically a custom shape has slightly updated properties... first of all "StrokeStyle" is no longer a valid property. Just use 'stroke'. Same thing with FillStyle.

Also -- 'dashArray' is no longer valid, now it's just 'dash' -- so I'm sure there are more things that changed that I'm not recalling...  right, such as 'lineWidth' is now 'strokeWidth'...

Also -- the way you show or don't show strokes and fills has changed...  yep, pretty much most of the way you used to do it has been changed slightly. 'drawFunc' is now 'sceneFunc' also...

```
var ctx = layer.getContext();

var customShape01 = new Kinetic.Shape({ 

    sceneFunc: function(ctx) { 

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(162.1, 213.8);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(162.1, 213.8, 180.7, 215.3, 193.5, 214.5);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(205.8, 213.7, 221.8, 212.3, 222.8, 221.4);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(222.9, 221.7, 222.9, 222.0, 222.9, 222.3);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(222.9, 232.4, 204.6, 232.7, 192.0, 227.1);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(179.4, 221.5, 163.1, 213.8, 162.1, 213.8);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStrokeShape(this);
   }, 

     id: 'customShape01',
     fill: 'rgb(255, 0, 255)',
     stroke: 'black',
     strokeWidth: 2,
     lineJoin: 'round',
     dash: [5,5],
     dashEnabled: 'true',
     strokeEnabled: 'true'   

});
```

check out a full working sample (you'll have to allow popups).
http://jsfiddle.net/axVXN/1/